# Communicate with <webview> in Electron

Tags: electron

I have a `<webview>` in my Electron app. I'd like to have safe "foreign" communication, the way I would with an `iframe` through `postMessage`. So for example:

`webview.executeJavaScript("window.parent.postMessage('all done!')");`

Is my only choice for communication with this subwebview to turn on `nodeIntegration` so that I can use `sendToHost`? Turning on all of `nodeIntegration` just for this one feature seems like overkill.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can access Electron APIs in the `webview` [preload](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-view-tag/#preload) script, including IPC, even when `nodeIntegration` is disabled. Your preload script can inject functions into the global namespace that will then be accessible within the page loaded in the `webview`. A simple example:

`webview-preload.js`:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')    

global.pingHost = () => {
  ipcRenderer.sendToHost('ping')
}
```

`webview-index.html`:

```
<script>
  pingHost()
</script>
```

`window-index.html`:

```
<script>
  const webview = document.getElementById('mywebview')
  webview.addEventListener('ipc-message', event => {
    // prints "ping"
    console.log(event.channel)
  })
</script>
```

Comment: This was just the answer I was looking for. This works for sending a message from the webview to the window. How would I send a message from the window to the webview?

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk did you try `webview.send()` ?

Comment: @psulek I ended up figuring it out. I think I ended up using webview.send() ya. Thanks.

Comment: Hi,I am trying the same thing but doesnt seem to be working https://discuss.atom.io/t/communicate-between-guest-webview-and-render-process/52118

Comment: Anything like this for windows? Or are child windows required to talk to the main process to communicate with other windows?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way
Communication is

Note:
(main.js or app.js or background.js or process.js ) no need to pass (directly pass component to  component),i succesffully implemented in electron:3.1.10
for print html webview.

**Window To Webview**

example1.html

```
    <webview id="paper" style="width:300px;height:800px" src="file:///static/mywebview.html" nodeintegration></webview>
```

example1.js

```
 var webview = document.getElementById("paper");
  webview.send("ping",data);
```

**getting data from mycomponent or window(i send directly form component)**

mywebview.html

```
<!---what data you want show----!>
```

mywebview.js

```
    const {
        ipcRenderer
    } = require('electron')                                                                            
  //data from window                                                                   
    ipcRenderer.on('ping', (e, data) => { console.log(data) })
```

**webview to window**

Webview to window(direct pass to component)

mywebview.js

```
 ipcRenderer.sendToHost("readyCompanyInfo",data)
```

in my window eg i use vue (mycomponent.vue or mypage)

example1.html

```
const ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
webview.addEventListener("ipc-message",(event)=>{

const {args,channel}=event;

if(channel=="readyCompanyInfo")
{
console.log(channel,args)
//here you can see data what u passed from webview to window
console.log(args[0])

}
})
```